# ShadowCopy folder stays empty after creating a AppDomain

Tags: c#, .net, appdomain

I create a new `AppDomain` like this

```
var setup = new AppDomainSetup
{
    ShadowCopyFiles = "true",
    ShadowCopyDirectories = executableFolderPath, // a semicolon separated list of three directory
    CachePath = shadowCopyFolderPath, // a custom path for the ShadowFiles
    AppDomainInitializer = new AppDomainInitializer(AppDomainInit),
    AppDomainInitializerArguments = initArgs, // shadowCopyFolderPath + executableFolderPath
    ApplicationBase = root.BaseDirectory // the base directory of the current AppDomain
};
var domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(domainName, AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence, setup);
```

I am using MEF to access defined types within the created `AppDomain`, where the `MEFLoader` is part of another Assembly that is not referenced within any assembly of the new created AppDomain.

```
Type typeToCreate = typeof(MEFLoader);
var loader = (MEFLoader)domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(
    typeToCreate.Assembly.FullName,
    typeToCreate.FullName,
    false,
    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.CreateInstance,
    null,
    args,
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    null);
```

So far, so good. This works all quite well. But I want to share some Assemblies between the AppDomain, therefore I added a `SharedLibraryFolder`. So may folderstructure is:

```
RootAppDomain
- SharedLibraries
- ChildAppDomain
  - ChildApp1
  - ChildApp2
```

Where for ChildAppDomain 1 the `executableFolderPath` looks like:

```
"C:\Sample\Path\RootAppDomain\ChildAppDomain\ChildApp1;C:\Sample\Path\RootAppDomain\SharedLibraries"
```

Now I would guess that booth folder get copied to the `ShadowCopyFolder` and all assemblies get loaded. 
But when I look into the folder right after the new AppDomain (ChildApp1) is created (before the MEFLoader instance is created) the folder is empty. At this point I also checked the loaded Assemblies for the created ChildApp1 AppDomain, which only contains the `mscorelib` at this state.
Rigth after the `MEFLoader` instance is created the `ShadowCopyFolder` is still empty and the loaded Assemblies are increased by the `MEFLoader` Assembly. If I now create a instance using MEF the ChildApp1.dll is loaded into the ChildApp1 AppDomain and the `ShadowCopyFolder` contains a copy of the ChildApp1 folder. But the `SharedLibraries` still wasn't copied.

**My question is when exactly are the shadowcopies created and why are some folders (SharedLibraries) not copied. In addition I would like to ask how the appdomain determines which assembly it loads (i.e. IIS always load all)**